# Unwanted Loop Workbook_AfterSave

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macros and I used the `Workbook_AfterSave` function on VBA. For some reason, it keeps looping the save function. I don't know how to get rid of this. It saves the excel file forever and eventually crashes. This is the code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Do pay attention to the tags you select.  Nearly all of them provide usage guidance text.  The `VB.NET` tag, for instance tells you not to use of for VBA posts; the `macros` tag tells you not to use it for VBA posts.

Comment: Why do you want to save the workbook after you just saved the workbook?  (Is it just to change the name of the active workbook?  Is it to create a second copy of what you just saved to another location?  Or is it something else?)

Answer (score 1):

Add in a Static variable to prevent the recursion:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
  Static bHere as Boolean
  If bHere then Exit Sub

  bHere = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  bHere = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`EnableEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-enableevents-property-excel) property of the Application object to `False` to prevent the event firing again when you save in the `Workbook_AfterSave` event.

The code below gets the current status of the flag; sets it to `False`; runs your original code; and then resets the flag in the error handler. You should have an error handler here in case of an IO error during your save and putting the reset in the error handler ensures the `EnableEvents` setting is restored to the original value. Example code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    Dim blnSetting As Boolean

    ' IO operations should have an event handler
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    ' remember existing setting and set flag to False
    blnSetting = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' your original code
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

CleanExit:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' handle error
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    End If

    ' reset the Application flag here
    Application.EnableEvents = blnSetting

End Sub
```